# How to use switchMap with login form submit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

How should one use switchMap operator with submit login form, so the form won't get submitted multiple times to backend?

I have tried using subjects but it doesn't work for me.
Here is my code.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';

private submitStream = new Subject<Event>();
@Output() observ = this.submitStream.asObservable();

formSubmit(event: Event) {
  this.submitStream.next(event);
}
```

and in HTML on button:

```
(click)="formSubmit($event)"
```

How to make it work?
Or simpler way without using subjects?

The expected behavior is that `http` submit post will get cancelled whenever user clicks the submit button multiple times, only the last click will go to backend.

Comment: I think you're swatting a fly with a nuclear missile here. Why not simply disable the button until you get a response from your service?

Comment: @Brandon this is how I currenty handle this, but I want to know out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have figured it out, just used this in constructor and it worked nicely:

```
this.submitStream.pipe(switchMap(() => this.authService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)))
        .subscribe((result) => {
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }, (err) => {
            this.error = err;
            this.modalService.showSnackError(err.error.message);
        });
```